# Excel Print-Papersize in RPGLE (Apache POI)

Tags: java, db2, rpgle, rpg

i try to setup the papersize to print my Excel with the Scott Klement - Excel-Tool.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this correctly. I have an HSSF source where the Java methods are defined. In the RPGLE program, I then call them up accordingly to apply them to my Excel file.

Can someone explain me how to define the java methods correctly in the HSSF source? I tried it using the existing and working examples, but it doesn't work for me. No matter how I try I would like to understand how to implement the methods correctly.

Edit:
I don't quite understand it yet. Here would be the Java method.

```
XSSFPrintSetup.setPaperSize(...) 

/** 
 * Set the paper size as enum value. 
 * 
 * @param size value for the paper size. 
 */ 
public void setPaperSize(PaperSize size) { 
   setPaperSize((short) (size.ordinal() + 1)); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the signatures of the java methods you want to call ?  And how you declare it in your RPG ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I don't quite understand it yet. Here would be the Java method.
'code'
XSSFPrintSetup.setPaperSize(...)
/**
 * Set the paper size as enum value.
 *
 * @param size value for the paper size.
 */
public void setPaperSize(PaperSize size) {
  setPaperSize((short) (size.ordinal() + 1));
}
'code'

Comment: You should make edits to the question rather than just comment. I put your code in the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to translate the java signature of your methods in RPG
For java objets, and for java methods.

example : Java method:

```
public String setValCelluleRec(int numSheet, int numRow, String numColStr, String typeCell,
        String valueStr, BigDecimal valueDecimal, String numColRecStr, String valueRec)
        throws FmkException { ... }
```

In RPG :

```
/COPY QSYSINC/QRPGLESRC,JNI 


dcl-pr setValCelluleRecJ like(jstring)
       extproc(*java : AlimenteXLSModele : 'setValCelluleRec');
  *n int(10) value; // numSheet
  *n int(10) value; // numRow
  *n like(jstring); // numCol
  *n like(jstring); // typeCell
  *n like(jstring);  // valueStr
  *n like(BigDecimal); // valueDecimal
  *n like(jstring); // numColRec
  *n like(jstring);  // valueRec
end-pr;
```

I don't use directly Scott Klement tools but I call directly POI methods. Perhaps in the tool there a re utilities to help java call and declarations